# Node module works for electron but not for Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, electron

I have a small development environment for electron with mocha tests. I installed the image-thumbnail library and I recompiled it for electron:

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`

But when I run the tests with mocha I get the error:

```
Error: The module '/home/jose/Dev/JavaScripts/Electron/Ng6ETesting/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

I run `npm rebuild` and then it works for the test case but the app does not raise. The error now is:

```
Error: The module '/home/jose/Dev/JavaScripts/Electron/Ng6ETesting/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Mocha are you using?

Comment: @Owner mocha@5.2.0